# Something similar to strpos() for arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I've been getting a lot of spam coming from my contact form recently, so I decided to add a little bit of validation to the "message" portion of the form. I've written a function that I thought would work to weed out the most commonly used words I see in my spammy emails from the form, but it's always returning false when I run it.

Here's the function:

```
function spamCheck($input) {
    $flags = array('cialis', 'viagra', 'erection', 'pharmac', 'porn', 'anal', 'bondage', 'insurance', 'ringtone', 'poker', 'casino', 'gambl', 'whore', 'nipple', 'shit', 'realt', 'shemale', 'valium');
    $input = explode(' ', $input);
    foreach($input as $word) {
        $word = trim($word, '",.!?\';:*');
        foreach($flags as $flag) {
            if(strpos(strtolower($word), $flag)) {
                return $word;
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'll notice that some of the words in the blacklist aren't complete. Such as "gambl", which could be sent in an email as "gambling" or "gamble" or "gambler" or "gambles" or "gambled". This is why I was using strpos() from within the foreach loop, so that it would match partial strings, not just exact strings.

Any ideas what's causing this to fail?

Comment: Are you sure `$input` is an array? Also, you don’t need `exit` after `return`.

Comment: Guess I should mention that I don't want it to simply return "true" if there's a match found. I want the original word returned that was matched so that I can let the user know it was flagged as spam in case it was a legitimate use-case.

Comment: No, input is a string that I explode into an array within the function.

Comment: Ohh... sorry. Didn’t notice the line `$input = explode(' ', $input);` and therefore asked the stupid question.

Comment: strpos will return position. If your string exist in first place, the it will return 0. So If condition is false in this case.

Comment: Change the seventh line of your code to `if(strpos(strtolower($word), $flag) !== false)` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
function spamCheck($input){
    $flags = array('cialis', 'viagra', 'erection', 'pharmac', 'porn', 'anal', 'bondage', 'insurance', 'ringtone', 'poker', 'casino', 'gambl', 'whore', 'nipple', 'shit', 'realt', 'shemale', 'valium');
    $input = explode(' ', $input);
        foreach($input as $word){
        $word = trim($word, '",.!?\';:*');
            foreach($flags as $flag){
                if(strpos(strtolower($word), $flag) !== false){
                return $word;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
}

$spam = spamCheck("Download free ringtones for your mobile phone.");
print($spam); // will print "ringtones"
```

Read more about the return values of [strpos](http://php.net/strpos).

**Update:** The regex equivalent of your function:

```
function spamCheck($input){
    $flags = array('cialis', 'viagra', 'erection', 'pharmac', 'porn', 'anal', 'bondage', 'insurance', 'ringtone', 'poker', 'casino', 'gambl', 'whore', 'nipple', 'shit', 'realt', 'shemale', 'valium');
    $pattern = "/\\b[a-z]*(?:".implode("|", $flags).")[a-z]*\\b/i";
        if(preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches)){
        return $matches[0];
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works for now. I guess I'm gonna delve into creating a regex to make the matches, since that seems to be the buzz I'm getting here. But I'll use this until I can work out a pattern that'll do the job.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man! Most people wouldn't have taken the time to add additional details after their answer had been accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function spamCheck($input) {
$flags = array('cialis', 'viagra', 'erection', 'pharmac', 'porn', 'anal', 'bondage', 'insurance', 'ringtone', 'poker', 'casino', 'gambl', 'whore', 'nipple', 'shit', 'realt', 'shemale', 'valium');
$input = explode(' ', $input);
foreach($input as $word) {
    $word = trim($word, '",.!?\';:*');
     foreach($flags as $fl){
      if(strpos($word,$fl) !== false ){ // edited as user requested
          return $word;
     }
}
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: I know in_array would have been a better choice, but to use it I would have to add every variation of a word to the blacklist array. "pharmac" wouldn't match "pharmacy" or "pharmaceutical", etc.

Comment: Thanks. @Sharanya Dutta beat you to it though.

Comment: Unless you had mentioned your comment in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using regex here with preg_replace. Doing manual string searches will affect efficiency and leave a lot of edge cases unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

A few modifications and it works:

```
    function spamCheck($input) {
    $flags = array('cialis', 'viagra', 'erection', 'pharmac', 'porn', 'anal', 'bondage', 'insurance', 'ringtone', 'poker', 'casino', 'gambl', 'whore', 'nipple', 'shit', 'realt', 'shemale', 'valium');

    $input = preg_replace('/[",.!?\';:*]/', '', $input);

    $input = explode(' ', $input);

    foreach($input as $word) {
      foreach($flags as $flag) {
        if(strpos(strtolower($word), $flag) !== false) {
          return $word;
        }
      }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work for exact matches. However, the partial words in the blacklist such as "gambl" and "pharmac" don't match. That's why I didn't go with in_array first, because it only does exact matches.

Comment: to test strpos you need `===` and `!=` operators, I was probably the problem.